# Authenticating an External Restful Web-service from UI5/Fiori application

Tags: web-services, rest, sapui5, sap-fiori

We have a requirement to consume a **External** RESTful web service from UI5 application. We need to develop a complete Fiori app **without** using ODATA service published in gateway.

Kindly help me out in **authenticating** an external web service. Will this requirement is feasible to implement when considering the front end roles and back end roles?

It will be more helpful for me if you share the code snippet for performing/consuming **CRUD** operations on external services from **UI5** application including **authentication**.

Regards

Phani Poorna

Comment: You should simply authenticate as you would with any other REST service. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: @Qualiture Actually we are in analyzing phase of this requirement. Just wanted to know the consistency and feasibility of the requirement in terms of security and fiori application scope. Please share your views

Comment: @Qualiture Actually i know how to call Odata service using sap.ui.model.odata.Odata() class. But not sure with performing crud operations on external services in UI5. It will be more beneficial to me if you share code snippet or reference doc for my particular requirement.

Answer (score 3):

The authentication you are looking for is not something that you should build into your app, but should be provided by the infrastructure your application is running on. Your ID provider (e.g. R/3 or Active Directory), in which you login to, should provide your browser with the necessary tokens or cookies. The respective sub-systems should in turn decide to give you access based on the cookies, tokens or certificates that you bring along.

A bit like this:

[image]

Many Fiori apps are running on the same R/3 environment as the user logs into. As this is the same system, it is trusted by default. This is why you don't have to do much to get a decent response from your service. However, if you want to connect to an external system, you will have to put some IDP plumbing in place. This usually involves things such as establishing a trust between de IDP and the external service.

As mentioned, authorisation should not be part of your app, hence no code samples in this answer. I hope answer provides you with enough pointers to find a solution for your particular situation. This is a tough topic though, read up on it (there's lot of info on SCN and the help-section) and don't be shy to ask for help from a basis consultant if necessary.

Also, please don't step into the pitfall of building your own authentication (e.g. basic authentication or oAuth), as it is insecure by default. The reason for this is because your Javascript, including embedded algorithms and tokens are readable by anyone the has access to the app.

Comment: Upvoted because of your first and last paragraph's first sentence

Comment: @Qualiture: Safety first ;)

Comment: @jpenninkhof Thank you very much for giving me inside overview of service calls and guidelines. It is very much helpful. As you said many are running on same R/3. you mean to say its a embeded deployement right(Gateway installed on same backend system). But in our case its a central deployment approach. We cannot connect our backend through RFC with gateway. Instead we can host Resftul service. Also Basic auth and Oauth are supported. Kindly suggest me some tips to develop this requirement. Will it be a consistent solution to make?

Comment: @PhaniPoorna I tried to make the answer as generic as possible, but indeed made some hints about an embedded Gateway (service 1). In your situation, you will have to consider your backend to be service 2. You will have to get a token from the IDP (probably the embedded Gateway system) and use the token to authenticate with Service 2. I would recommend going with SAML if it's available (if your landscape is based on SAP software, SAML is definitely an option). OAuth requires back-end logic to make things work. Basic auth is fine too, as long as your credentials on both systems are the same.

Comment: @jpenninkhof our back is an SAP system. It has only OAuth and Basic Auth as per the current release by SAP. As you said in terms of security don't use basic auth and Oauth mechanicms. We have only those two options actually and we might use Basic auth only(as users have same creds on our backend and also gateway front end). But i am bit worried after you specified about security. :( As per your opinion and experince will this requirement will be a consistent solution to implement? Actually we are in the analyzing phase of this req. Please share your views . It wil lbe very helpful to me :)

Comment: @PhaniPoorna: Basic auth is secure as long as you do it over an ssl line. Do note that your landscape probably also supports SAML. This doc may give you some pointers: https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/92/5c22518bc72214e10000000a44176d/content.htm